# Create multiple merge requests from Command Line

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible somehow to create multiple GitLab merge requests from current_branch to another 4 branches with command line? Right now it works fine only for branch_1, because I have commit. After that commit is pushed to branch1, merge request created and next branches has no commits to be pushed and push failed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

for BRANCH in branch1 branch2 branch3 branch4
do
  git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=$BRANCH -o merge_request.remove_source_branch
done
```

Comment: I added info that I am trying with Gitlab

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/  https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/merge_requests.html

Comment: Thank @KamilCuk that I was needed.